# Using HandbrakeCLI once user has uploaded a video

Tags: php, encode

I want to be able to encode videos eith handbrake CLI once the user has uploaded them.  I have no idea how to go about doing this, thr inly guess i can think of is to use php's exec() command and execute the program from there.  But wouldnt that come with risks?

Or is there any other way to do this? I basically need to encode the videos into a web playable format with baseline 3 encoding so that they play through he JWPlayer on all devices.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`exec()` doesn't have to be unsafe as long as you're careful with what you're executing.

Alternatively, and a better solution, would be to use a producer - consumer model. Everytime a video is uploaded, add a reference to it to a queue. Have a CLI script that monitors the queue, and as long as the queue has videos that need to be processed, the script does the encoding.

You can use a database, or even just a directory as a queue. For example, upload all new videos to a directory `unprocessed`. The consumer script can pick up videos from there, encode them and place them in a folder called `processed`.

This allows you to control how many videos should be processed concurrently (by varying the number of consumers). `exec()` on user upload doesn't allow that, and you risk the chance of bringing your server down to its knees.

Edit:

If you intend to use more than one consumer, I wouldn't recommend using the directory-as-queue model as you risk the chance of a race condition.

Comment: Thank you, Can you point me to some consumer scripts that would do this?

Comment: Most probably you would have to write your own. I doubt there would be any consumer scripts that suit your needs.